# openpyxl - Limitation of DataValidation

Tags: python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I'm using `openpyxl` to interact with excel file.

I want to generate an excel file which has some `data_validation` so that users are able to choose value from the dropdown list, the value of dropdown list is based on value of another cell. But when I generate a large number of `data_validation`, the excel file crashes and I lose all my `data_validation`

Currently, I'm using a loop to loop through rows add add the `data_validation` to cell in the row.
The example code is:

```
for row in range(3, MAXIMUM_ROW): 
  test = DataValidation(type="list",
                          formula1='=INDIRECT("Prefix."&E{})'.format(row))
  test.add('G{}:G{}'.format(row, row))
  worksheet.add_data_validation(test)
```

I want the `MAXIMUM_ROW` is the maximum number of rows in a worksheet (which is `1,048,576` I believe) but when I set the `MAXIMUM_ROW` above `60,000` the generated excel file crashes and all the `data_validation` are lost.
I'm not sure if it's the limitation of excel itself or the limitation of `openpyxl`.

If anyone encountered this issue before and figured out a way to resolve it, please help me. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why are you applying separate validations to each cell in the column? That's going to lead to a huge file and a massive overhead for Excel.

Comment: @CharlieClark because the dropdown list value of the G cell must depend on the value of E cell in the same row. When I search for the solution, most of them use for loop and create a new data_validation then assign to desired cell.
But I figure out the way to resolve it, by using ROW() and COLUMN()

Comment: I've not worked much with data validations but I'd have thought relative or absolute coordindates for formulae over a range of cells should be possible. There's no restriction in the specification but I'm not surprised that Excel crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured out how to do it. It seems that the problem is that somehow `Excel` prevents creating too much `DataValidation` using `openpyxl`.

At first, I thought it was because Excel limits the number of unique `data_validation` in a single sheet to `60k`. But when I tried manually dragging to apply `data_validation`of a cell to following cells in the same column in a single sheet, I saw that it could exceed that number.

So after that, I thought it was because I created too many `DataValidation` by `openpyxl` in a single process, which causes problems when I save them to the output file. But when I chunked the `DataValidation` in order to save `10k` `DataValidation` at a time, it still fails when the total `data_validation` generated by `openpyxl` exceeds `65k`.

At this point, I noticed that I could apply a single `DataValidation` to all cells in a column as long as all of them used the same `formula`.
So I tried to find out a way that I could create just a single `DataValidation` and dynamically apply it to all cells in a column. The hard part here is that the `DataValidation` list is based on the value of another cell in the same row (which made me use the `INDIRECT` function).
Then I figured out that `Excel` does have the functions `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` which return the current `row` and `column` of the current cell.

So I updated my code as follows:

```py
data_validation = DataValidation(type="list",
        formula1='=INDIRECT("Prefix."&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-2))')
data_validation.add('G{}:G{}'.format(start_row, MAXIMUM_ROW))
worksheet.add_data_validation(data_validation)
```

By this way, I only need to create a single `data_validation` and apply to all cells in a column.

I was surpised that this method is not commonly used, I've been searching for it for a while and almost all the answers from SO is just creating a for loop and create `data_validation`  for each cell just like I did in the question.

Hope this helps anyone who runs into the same issue as me.